# For ELF file, how to tell which section contains execution binary code?

Tags: elf

I am studying ELF and having a doubt for a while. I tried to search for the answer but in vain. I'd apprciated if somebody could give me the answer or guide me to the place to find an answer.

Almost all the documents I read about ELF said .text section contains executable binary code (and .data contains data....). However, when I used readelf to see the sections contain in an obj file, I saw no .text section but a section called i.main which contains the executable code (from the code contained in this section I found the machine code). The following shows the sections parsed by readelf

`Section Headers:
    [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
    [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
    [ 1] i.main            PROGBITS        00000000 000034 00000a 00  AX  0   0  2
    [ 2] .arm_vfe_header   PROGBITS        00000000 000040 000004 00      0   0  4
    [ 3] .comment          PROGBITS        00000000 000044 0001c6 00      0   0  1
    [ 4] .debug_frame      PROGBITS        00000000 00020a 00003c 00      0   0  1
    [ 5] .debug_info       PROGBITS        00000000 000246 000088 00      0   0  1
    [ 6] .debug_info       PROGBITS        00000000 0002ce 0000dc 00      0   0  1
    [ 7] .debug_line       PROGBITS        00000000 0003aa 000030 00      0   0  1
    [ 8] .debug_line       PROGBITS        00000000 0003da 000044 00      0   0  1
    [ 9] .debug_loc        PROGBITS        00000000 00041e 000014 00      0   0  1
    [10] .debug_macinfo    PROGBITS        00000000 000432 000308 00      0   0  1
    [11] .debug_pubnames   PROGBITS        00000000 00073a 00001b 00      0   0  1
    [12] __ARM_grp..debug_ GROUP           00000000 000758 000008 04     14  14  4
    [13] .debug_abbrev     PROGBITS        00000000 000760 0005a4 00   G  0   0  1
    [14] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 000d04 000110 10     21  13  4
    [15] .rel.debug_frame  REL             00000000 000e14 000010 08     14   4  4
    [16] .rel.debug_info   REL             00000000 000e24 000018 08     14   5  4
    [17] .rel.debug_info   REL             00000000 000e3c 000038 08     14   6  4
    [18] .rel.debug_line   REL             00000000 000e74 000008 08     14   8  4
    [19] .rel.debug_pubnam REL             00000000 000e7c 000008 08     14  11  4
    [20] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 000e84 0000f2 00      0   0  1
    [21] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 000f76 0001b3 00      0   0  1
    [22] .ARM.attributes   ARM_ATTRIBUTES  00000000 001129 000044 00      0   0  1`

It seems that the section name can be arbitrarily chosen (am I right?) If so, then my questiones are

1. how to tell which section contains what? (for example, which section contains code and which section contains read only data....).
2. How to know the definition of each section, for example how do I know the section "[12]   __ARM_grp..debug_" is for what purpose?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

As for the first part of your question, when determining what sections contain code and which sections contain read only data, a good thing to look for is the section attribute flags.

With the `readelf -S` command, an `X` indicates that the section contains executable instructions, an `A` indicates that the section occupies memory during process execution, and a `W` indicates that the section should be writable.

So in your object file, there is one section, `i.main` that is executable, and it is also read only. The other sections aren't writable, but not read only since they aren't in memory at all.

I'm not very familiar with ARM binaries, so I can't really address the other parts of your question.

Comment: Also note that in an executable (or shared library), sections are *not necessary*, and could be completely stripped, though this isn't common. At runtime, only *segments* matter.